# I can't access my home server using my public IP from local network

Tags: domain-name-system, router, nat, dmz

> I've seen this question [I can't access my public IP from local network](https://serverfault.com/questions/370147/i-cant-access-my-public-ip-from-local-network) but I think it's different

I have a Vodafone Spain router from Huawei, model HG253sV2. In my local network I setup a HTTP server. I can access it from my local network using the local IP. I've also setup No-IP and DMZ, so I can access the server from the outside. Both are working fine BUT if I try to enter my website using my public IP address or the No-IP DNS from my local network I can't access my server. It redirects to a Vodafone router configuration panel.

**Short** I can't access my HTTP server using my public IP address if I do it from the local network. Connections from the outside network are fine and work as expected.

What can I do to use the DNS name (or public IP address) in my local network?

(I know I can edit /etc/hosts but I prefer something which doesn't need to involve changing files in every computer on my local network)

[image: Vodafone Configuration Panel]

Comment: Why do you think it is different of the previous question ? Do you enable the hairpin NAT ? Or use a DNS with the internals IP as you propose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](http://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding and DMZ are related to sessions initiated on the WAN side and redirected as configured to the proper local machine.

For that reason, unless you have advanced configuration or shell access to your router (which does not appear to be your case), it is not possible to define the rules needed in it.  Even if you could, it would cause a conflict with the router's built-in configuration web-server port which also doesn't appear customizable.

So if you absolutely need to do that, you'd need a more customizable router.

Comment: Home use is not topical on SF. Answering off topic questions implicitly encourages them.