# I can load an IIS hosted website via the Internet but not locally

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2

I have just changed the bindings to use SSL for a website hosted in IIS on an AD Domain Controller.

The new binding is IP: all unassigned - Hostname: site.domain.com - Port: 443

I can access this new domain perfectly via the internet using https://site.domain.com but when I attempt to load it locally (RDP into the server) I get page cannot be displayed.

I have not made any changes to the local DNS (the server is set to use the local DNS), which is suspect may be related but even so, a ping to site.domain.com resolves to the correct IP address.

I am unfortunately limited to one binding for this particular site (limitation with the application).

In short, remote loads but local doesn't.

Thanks

[image: ping traces from remote and local machines]

Comment: Does ping site.domain.com really resolve to "correct" IP address (the one you get when you run `ipconfig` on your web server?

Comment: Hi @dusan.bajic. Yes both the server and my local machine resolve to the external ip address of the server, x.x.x.108. I've added an image showing ping traces with the info.

Comment: What is the local address of IIS server (not the one you get when you try to ping it, but the one that you get as an output of `ipconfig` command on webserver?

Comment: The local IP address is 192.168.254.253.

Comment: Read these answers: http://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

Comment: @dusan.bajic, the solution was to disable strict naming on the domain in question. http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx. Add an answer since you deserve the rep.

Comment: I really can't do that, I have almost no knowledge about that article's subject (and honestly fail too see how it relates to your question). But I believe that it is perfectly fine if you add an answer to your own question.

Comment: You got me to the answer with the hairpin NAT term. That lead to disabling it