# vSphere ESXi and assigning public IPs to VM

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a server with ESXi installed. And added some Virtual Machines (Ubuntu).

All the VMs are having a private IP, but how can I assign a public IP to a VM?

What I want is to assign a public ip (IPv6 preferred) to a VM, so I can reach a specific VM based of an IP.

What I want is to be able to ssh into a specific VM, on port 20 and the assigned IP. And the same for websites, so port 80 etc forwarding.

I have already a VM Port Group in ESXi, and Virtual Machines. See this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/efnrun70s7te8e5/a.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Your virtual switch doesn't have any relation to assigning ip addresses to your virtual machines. As EEAA stated in his answer, you assign ip addresses to virtual machines the same way you assign them to physical machines. You perform NAT, port forwarding and routing for virtual machines the same way you do for physical machines. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I suggest you get some basic virtualisation training and re-read what this site is for and what it's not

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You assign public addresses the exact same way you'd assign private addresses.

Of course you will need to ensure that proper routing is in place, otherwise nothing will work.

Alternatively, you can port forward from your router to these VMs.

Comment: Added a picture to clarify it all.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't clarify anything. Give us as much detail as you can, including the entire network infrastructure between your ISP and the ESXi server.

Comment: What do you think needs to be clarified? Remember: Nothing *magical* happened just because someone said *virtual*. A network is still a network. A route is still a route.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things which we'd need to clarify to start with:

- Whether you actually want to dedicate a public IP address to that VM or whether you just want to access the two servers on that port
- Whether you want to be able to use the *public IP* internally as well as externally

Note: All of the below is explained with the assumption that by private IPs you mean an internal network address, accessible on your internal network, not private to the ESXi host.

If you purely wish to access the VM on those services from an **external** environment you can configure port forwarding on your internet facing router to forward the ports 22 (SSH) and 80 (HTTP) to the VM.

If you wish to access any arbitrary ports on the VM (**externally**) without re-configuring your network equipment constantly, the best plan would be to configure Network Address Translation (NAT) on your network equipment, to translate the(/a) public IP address through to the private internal address.

If you need to access this public IP address **internally** as well as externally, you'll need to configure your internet facing router to perform a (Loopback) hairpin NAT to reroute traffic directed from the internal network to the public IP address. More details about hairpin NAT here: [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)