# IP Forwarding Configurations

Tags: networking, router, linux-networking, forwarding, netcat

I am testing ip forwarding to recieve external connections from my computer at home. I did the following from my router settings:

[Turned off firewall of router and fedora, done forwarding settings, set netcat to listen to port 80 and checked connection via canyouseeme.org (also tried sending an http request to my public ip (from whatismyip.com) from my mobile internet connection.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1qnxtwIOTlCfm1ZVTgtcUtjT1J5bkc2WDVLOG9GY2JSb2FWd1Y4SUlhSGRyVEFOSmNDeGs)

What am i missing here?

Sorry for links, cannot upload images directly because of low rep.

P.S.: My router is Netmaster CBW 383Z4.

Comment: Does your router have a function to log forwarded connections? It would eliminate one leg of the problem. Post that info. I'm upvoting you, so that you can upload images (rep10 i think). Or, only upload the pictures, if the router actually shows forwarded connections.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find a log functionality (i do have wireshark though, if it can be of help). I googled netmaster (modem brand) forwarding, some people have gone through the same steps and claim it works fine for them.

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking connections to you on certain ports to 'motivate' you to take the more expensive Internet option at the company. Try another high port like 23456. Yes, tcpdump/Wireshark would be useful. Can you use them? The filtering specification and output interpretation may not be easy for you. You could also edit your post to mention the exact model of router you want to configure logged port-forwarding for.

Comment: I edited the question including that. I was also guessing problem might be with the ISP blocking, maybe i should check with their call center. It didn't work with port 23456 either, btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](http://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Comment: My testing does not involve hairpin, i connect from my mobile phone, not from my home wifi.

Comment: The problem apperantly was my ISP blocking incoming packets because i did not pay extra to get a static ip. I bought a static ip and now i can reach my computer from an outside connection.