# Cannot log in to RDP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote

I have 2 IPs on my Windows Server 2012. 1st is local the 2nd is real public.

Whenever I try to login using RDP from a windows 8 from inside the network of the local IP, I can easily log in. However, whenever I try using the public IP, I get the below error.

The server is on a domain and I am specifying the domain name as such NomainName\administrator

[image]

Things I have done till now:

```
added the ADMINISTRATOR account to the Remote Desktop Users built in group.
inside Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System and under Remote Desktop Settings, the settings are turned on to allow remote connections.
The built in firewall is stopped (temporarily) to test if that is the issue.
The ANTIVIRUS KASPERSKY's firewall is stopped (temporarily) to test if that is the issue.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the event logs on the server for error messages regarding the failed login attempt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](http://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider no. any walk through how to check them?

Comment: First of all, are you sure that your traffic is routed to your server properly when connecting from the outside? Launch at least this command on the server to check whether an inbound connection appears on the server: `netstat -anp tcp 1 | find ":3389"` - it shoud go through the normal states `LISTENING`, `ESTABLISHED` etc. Or use network analyzer such as Wireshark. If there is no connection, `tracert` your server's IP from the outside - may be you are trying to login to the wrong server.

Comment: @vic I think you are talking about something else. I have a direct real IP on the machine, no need for NATing

Comment: @tony9099 Maybe I misunderstood. Aren't you trying to access your server on its public IP from within the LAN?

Comment: @vic no. Im trying to enter the real IP directly from outside... local is just to access from local

Comment: @Sergio the dialog and the error messages indicates that the RDP client and the server can communicate with each other, it's just the login that fails. That basically rules out all neworking problems. The event log on the server can be found in the computer management console.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider exactly. I can ping the machine and the RDP can reach it when I put the IP in the box. It's just that it does not log in :/

Comment: @tony9099 in inferred that much from the screenshots, hence my question about the event logs on the server.

Comment: @tony9099 Apologies then. I guess you already thought about trivial things such as caps lock, keymapping. And yes, definitely check the logs.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider in the logs, what shall I look for?

Comment: @Gerald I tried no to be that simple - do you think that his server is the only RDP server around? My question was if he is 100% sure that he is connecting to the right server. And disabling firewalls is actually more pointless when we already see the error message, so why not comment on that? tony9099 if you are indeed connecting to the right server, I would like to mention that problems like this are often caused by inconsistent name resolution, that is if your server's and client's names resolve to the correct IPs and their IPs back to their names (reverse DNS) - check for this, please.

Comment: Could you also try entering your credentials in the `Administrator@domain` format, please? Possibly removing them from (and possibly re-adding to) the Windows Credentials Manager.