# Not able to open doors on router

Tags: router, port, port-forwarding, cassandra

I have a Cassandra broker in my lan and I want to allow to execute query on it from the web.

So I made an association on my router (vodafone station revolution) between the external port 9042 with the internal port 9042 (both in port forwarding and port triggering sections). Also, I set a static ip for the broker inside the lan. Finally I set up Static NAT on the broker to redirect all the traffic towards it.

Unfortunately when I try telnet myip:9042 the connection is refused.

I have also disabled the router firewall.
I suppose that the problem is the vodafone station and its high-level application.

Is there a low-level way to do what I want to do?

Comment: To help you debug where the connection refused message originates from: the canonical [connection refused Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/725262/37681) - If you're testing the connection to the external ipaddress and port from within your LAN you may be running into a specific edge case where NAT routing frequently fails: Hairpin NAT https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

Comment: Ok verified and the process is listening. I have no firewall. I don't know if it is important by if on my machine I try telnet 127.0.0.1 9042 all works fine

Comment: See `netstat -tlnp` output and check that your Cassandra is not listening only for 127.0.0.1:9042 -- if it is, check from Cassandra manual how to make it listen to other interfaces.

Comment: mmm using netstat -tln -p TCP in the list of local addresses doesn't appear port 9042

Comment: using  lsof -n -i4TCP:9042 | grep LISTEN
I have obtained a single line when is showed 127.0.0.1:9042 so I modified cassandra configs to exposes another address as contact point. No results.
I still think the problem is in the port forwarding