# Connection refused on own domain name

Tags: networking

I have a server with a reverse proxy in an LXD container.

It's serving my websites fine but if I try to curl any of the domain names inside the server or any of the containers it gives me a Connection Refused.

It does work when I bypass the host by putting the local IP of another container in /etc/hosts

I really don't get what's going on with this setup, especially because it's reachable from the outside.

I'll be happy to provide more information if required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)