# Unable to connect to my winsock server using external IP

Tags: networking, ip, port-forwarding, tcpip

When I try to connect to my simple winsock server using my localhost/LAN IP, the connection is established with no problems.

However, if I attempt to do so using my external IP, I keep getting timeouts. Other tools, such as `canyouseeme.org` and `ping` also return timeout.

Port forwarding and disabling the firewall didn't change anything.

I've already asked this question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477792/unable-to-connect-to-my-winsock-server-using-external-ip) and I was told to move it here. That is, to link it here. Visit 
the above link to the full question, please.

Comment: What kind of router/firewall do you have, and can you post the configuration?

Comment: Where are you connecting from, when you attempt to use this external IP?  Are you connecting from a host outside your network?  If you are attempting to connect from inside this would likely be a hairpin  nat problem.

Comment: @RonTrunk My firewall is just default Windows firewall. My router is Orange Livebox 2.0 (you probably don't know it, as my ISP isn't an international company). [That's screenshot of the router's configuration page.](https://imgur.com/a/Qm0DOzo) I translated all the words into English, so you should be able to understand.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm connecting from my own computer, i.e. host inside my network. I haven't tried to connect from outside of it, yet (beyond the `canyouseeme.org` website).

Comment: Well, like I said, `hairpin NAT` problems.  If you are connecting from internal to internal, that is probably not going to work.  Search the terms 'hairpin nat'.  One answer from here.  https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

Comment: @Zoredache If I understand correctly, assuming that was the hairpin NAT problem, then `canyouseeme.org` should connect properly, while it actually timeouts.