# Is it possible to forward 127.0.0.1:port to publicip:4567?

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have a ruby server running , based on the following repository 
https://github.com/BuffaloWill/oxml_xxe

I am running Ubuntu without vnc installed. I tried to access the server via my public ip and couldn't proceed with it. I also searched for the code block to edit the localhost ip , which ended up unsuccessful.

So is there any method so that I can forward the 127.0.0.1 to my publicip , such a way I can access it from my local machine

Comment: If you're trying to reach the public IP and it's failing and assuming you haven't set up any forwards yet.. you need to forward the public IP to your internal IP (not localhost, localhost isn't routable).  Also, you need to look into [hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Comment: I have no internal IP configure in my server , I have only the public IP which I used to access the server via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
```

You can use iptables to forward request to local. 
But my recommendation is change listen address local to global.
Adding layer is not efficient.
You can found more details for iptables from [there](https://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial)

Open server.rb and add `set :bind, 'yourip'` confing to after requirements which is line 12 . I hope this will be work.

Comment: if you are saying the i should change the listen address from 127.0.0.1 to a global one , as i mentioned in the post , i am unable to do that . The reason is I couldnt find the code where I can change the listening IP

Comment: i tried adding the set : bind, 'myip' but i couldnt access. But initially i did the iptables method you answered and didnt remove the rule , is that the problem ?