# Accessing forwarded LAN server from same network

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a server behind NAT, with IP `192.168.0.42`. The router gets a dynamic IP from the ISP, which is regularly used to update a domain, let's say `myserver.example.com`. The router is configured to forward port 80 to the server.

This works fine externally and the server can be reached under `myserver.example.com`. However, if I try to access it via that domain from inside the network, it doesn't work. I think what's happening is that the client machine contacts `public-ip`, but then when the server responds it sends the response directly to the client machine but coming from `192.168.0.42`, which results in it being discarded by the client.

Is it possible to set up `iptables` on the server to detect this and respond correctly to the client? One difficulty is that I don't know what the public IP is. I couldn't find anything on the TP-Link router to fix this.

I know I could put a `hosts` entry on the client machine but that breaks if it's a laptop and is used externally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "NAT Boost" on the router fixed it.