# When connecting to my server through my domain, I get connection error. however, on a VPN it connects just fine

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, domain, connection, proxmox

New poster here so unsure if this is the correct stack exchange.

But basically, I use NPM (Nginx Proxy Manager) to direct internet traffic to various VMs running on my hub server running proxmox.

Whenever I try to connect to an internet SSL-based web application such as the web UI for NPM or Nextcloud, my web browser gives me a connection error. However, when I try to connect to the same domain that gave me a connection error through a VPN connection, the connection works just fine.

Why can't I connect to my own domains while being just on my normal connection no VPN?

Just a few things:
Everything is hosted on 1 single public IP.

Every web app has its own VM on an unfirewalled proxmox server (Every vm has its own built-in firewall, with relevant ports forwarded)

My domain name is: ambient-sky.co.uk

The VPN I use is just opera GXs proxy server.

Any ideas/tips would be helpful as I've never experienced this before.

If any logs or configurations are needed then I'd be happy to oblige.

[image: No VPN]

[image: VPN enabled]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Comment: No. Since I'm not using Hairpin NAT. Nor do I even know what that is :)

Comment: Do you use NAT? You include no information on your topology. My suspicion is that your problem is that you *don't* use hairpin NAT - hence the duplicate. Please read it.

Comment: to solve the problem, we need: /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/nginx/ where we see how you proxy it, the rest we can figure out later but using admin panel will not make it easier

Comment: @vidarlo Probably gonna need an explanation on NAT. I also have no idea what topology means. Do you mean my setup? I thought I explained that.. 
I did read it, and understood none of it. Please reclarify

Comment: @djdomi No such file or directory for /etc/network/interfaces.

No such file or directory for /etc/nginx.

NPM is running in a docker container.

Comment: @AmbientSkai That's a good hint that this question belongs at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). This site is for business IT problems, and we generally expect some level of knowledge. Posting home user questions on here tends to be unpleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not 100% sure if it was something I did or if my ISP forked up somewhere along the line. But now its working just fine

I sent an email to them asking if it was something on their end on why I couldn't locally resolve my own public IP. Woke up today, and now I can for some reason and my Domains are working locally again.. I never had a response from them on my email.

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: most dns changes are taken 24 till 96 hours to get through the world