# Looping forwarded and locally originating connections through port forwarding rules in firewalld

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding, firewalld, nftables

I have a Debian box running firewalld set up a as gateway NAT/router. This device has two NICS; `wan` --- public interface, assigned to the `external` firewalld zone, dynamically assigned IP address using DHCP ---, and `lan1` --- private interface, assigned to the `trusted` firewalld zone, statically assigned IP address of `192.168.0.1/16`.
The system is also configured to do NAT and port forwarding using firewalld:

```
(router) $> sudo firewall-cmd --info-zone=external
external (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: yes
  interfaces: wan
  sources:
  services: http https ssh
  ports: 8443/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
        port=8443:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
        port=443:proto=tcp:toport=443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
        port=80:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.0.2
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks: echo-reply echo-request fragmentation-needed neighbour-advertisement neighbour-solicitation packet-too-big port-unreachable router-advertisement router-solicitation time-exceeded
  rich rules:

(router) $> sudo firewall-cmd --info-zone=trusted
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: lan1 lo
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

(router) $> sudo sysctl -n net.ipv4.ip_forward
1
```

So far, so good. Devices within the internal `192.168.0.0/16` network can access the internet without any issues, and incoming connections on the `wan` interface to ports 80, 443, and 8443 are correctly forwarded to `192.168.0.2` where a reverse proxy instance is listening.

The problem arises when I want to use the public-facing IP address of the router from an internal device to access the reverse proxy on `192.168.0.2`. To illustrate this, I have two public DNS records associated with the public address of `wan`; `hq.mydomain.tld`, which is proxied through Cloudflare, and `gateway.mydomain.tld`, which instead points *directly* to the public IP address of `wan`.
If I hit `hq.mydomain.tld` from an internal device, the request in properly routed to `192.168.0.2`, as expected, as the request is first going to Cloudflare and then proxied back to my gateway:

```
$> curl -sS -D - https://hq.mydomain.tld -o /dev/null -L
HTTP/2 200
date: Sat, 16 Dec 2023 16:43:09 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
cache-control: public, max-age=600
...
```

However, if I instead hit `gateway.mydomain.tld` from an internal device, it seems as if no rules are applied and the request instead directly hits the router. Nothing is listening on the forwarded ports on the router, and so the request immediately fails.

```
$> curl -sS -D - https://gateway.mydomain.tld -o /dev/null -L
curl: (7) Failed to connect to gateway.mydomain.tld port 443 after 713 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

The same thing happens if instead of the public hostname I use the public IP of the router.

```
$> curl -sS -D - https://a.b.c.d -o /dev/null -L
curl: (7) Failed to connect to a.b.c.d port 443 after 18 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

This also happens if I `curl` from the router itself, either using it's own public IP address or `localhost`:

```
(router) $> curl -sS -D - https://a.b.c.d. -o /dev/null -L
curl: (7) Failed to connect to a.b.c.d port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

(router) $> curl -sS -D - https://localhost -o /dev/null -L
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

My question is then: **how do I configure firewalld (or its backend, nftables) to apply the public port forwarding rules to traffic originating from the internal network or from the router itself?**
Note that I can't use rules which directly use the public IP of `wan`, as this is a DHCP-assigned IP address and could change at any moment, rendering the rules useless.

I have tried a bunch of different things without success:

- Setting up identical port forwarding rules on the `trusted` zone.
- Using direct firewalld port forwarding rules on the loopback interface.
- Finally, I tried creating a firewalld policy using `trusted` (the internal zone) as a the ingress zone and `HOST` as the egress zone:

  ```
  (router) $> sudo firewall-cmd --info-policy=internal_fwd
  internal_fwd (active)
    priority: -1
    target: CONTINUE
    ingress-zones: trusted
    egress-zones: HOST
    services:
    ports:
    protocols:
    masquerade: no
    forward-ports:
    source-ports:
    icmp-blocks:
    rich rules:
  ```

  I really thought this would work, as such a policy applies to any traffic coming from the internal network that terminates in the router. However, it seems you can't use a policy with an `egress-zones: HOST` to forward ports to another device:

  ```
  (router) $> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=internal_fwd --add-forward-port=port=8443:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
  Error: INVALID_FORWARD: Policy 'internal_fwd': A 'forward-port' with 'to-addr' is invalid for egress zone 'HOST'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice is to NAT from external to internal.
First enable enable masquerading for that zone (I use public in this example)

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toaddr=192.168.x.x:toport=80
```

Owh yeah you also need to enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my question clearly explains that (1) masquerade is already enabled for my public-facing interface, (2) the `sysctl` parameter `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is already set to `1`, (3) traffic is already being NAT-ed and forwarded correctly, and (4) port forwarding is set up and working as expected. The problem is NOT forwarding from the external network to the internal one, but rather forwarding _within_ the internal network.

Comment: It's a bit weird and uncommon to forward ports from the internal network. I think you might better off with a VPN or proxy. Or can elaborate more in detail what exactly you want to forward from the internal network. You can have rules which filter the traffic from the internal network to public.

Comment: > It's a bit weird and uncommon to forward ports from the internal network. 

I understand, but I'm really just trying to replicate behavior that I have seen enabled by default in cheap off-the-shelves routers. What I really want is consistent behavior when accessing my public IP/hostname from within and from outside my internal network. I would like to always be able to access "gateway.mydomain.tld" and reach my web services, no matter if I'm connected to my intranet or I'm somewhere else. Maybe I could solve this with my internal DNS server, but that has it's own limitations.

Comment: Yes, this brings me to split-dns. Where you have a dns server who a public zone and internal zone. The domain name can be the same, in the internal zone you have the internal ip with associated to a record. And the same for the external zone. The external zone responds only ti queries on the internet, and the internal zone is scoped to the local network. For NAT, if traffic stays internal there is nothing to be translated from external to internal

Comment: I just figured out that what I want is called "hairpin NAT", and is actually a thing! https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback): here the final target is in the same LAN as the original source, so it will attempt to reply directly to it, bypassing the NAT inverse transformations that has to be done for replies. As the source doesn't know of the final target address (it doesn't know about 192.168.0.2 and so TCP replies from this source will be discarded with a TCP RST).

To handle NAT hairpinning, the replies also have to go through the NAT router so they can undergo the inverse NAT transformation. One easy way to do this is to also perform NAT on the source address in addition to the destination address. Any address that would get the reverse proxy server to reply through the NAT router is acceptable: its LAN address, its public address or any other address, including a fictional address, that would have the NAT router as gateway for the reverse proxy server. Here, for simplicity, the LAN address will be used (through the selective use of `masquerade`).

With pure *nftables* this could have been handled with a rule such as below in nat/postrouting:

```
iif lan1 oif lan1 ct status dnat masquerade
```

But this can't be done within *firewalld*. Instead using source address along output interface in a [rich rule](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html) can achieve the same. The rich rule will perform masquerade on the *trusted* zone when the source is within 192.168.0.0/16. This happens only when the packet has been routed back from 192.168.0.0/16 to 192.168.0.0/16 (ie to *lan1*, ie to *trusted*), meaning NAT was performed or this wouldn't have happened (except for the corner case of a misconfigured system in *trusted* zone that would use the gateway to reach other 192.168.0.0/16 addresses instead of directly):

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.0.0/16" masquerade'
```

This results in this diff for the *nftables* backend ruleset:

```
--- /tmp/ruleset1   2023-12-20 10:22:31.937292389 +0000
+++ /tmp/ruleset2   2023-12-20 10:26:31.155214737 +0000
@@ -519,6 +519,7 @@
    }
 
    chain nat_POST_trusted_allow {
+       ip saddr 192.168.0.0/16 oifname != "lo" masquerade
    }
 
    chain nat_POST_trusted_post {
```

which is exactly what is intended.

Alas that's not enough. Because the port forwarding rules were added to the *external* zone, no DNAT actually happened, because the only zone having been traversed is the *trusted* zone (tied to the `lan1` interface), but DNAT rules are performed only when the packet traverses the *external* zone (tied to the `wan` interface), and *firewalld* doesn't appear to have fallbacks (the relevant parts in the *nftables* backend use `goto` statements rather than `jump` statements, precluding the traversal of further chains). Port forwarding rules have to be duplicated in the *trusted* zone so they are also performed for this case:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-forward-port=port=8443:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-forward-port=port=443:proto=tcp:toport=443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.0.2
```

Use `--permanent` on all previous commands once correct behavior was verified.

Note: the reverse proxy's logs will all show the NAT router's 192.168.0.1 as source for all clients behind `lan1`. This appears unavoidable within the constraints of the rich rules language. Using directly *nftables*, one could have performed a prefix change in nat/postrouting like:

```
snat ip prefix to ip saddr map { 192.168.0.0/16 : 10.168.0.0/16 }
```

to still be able to distinguish individual clients from the *trusted* zone in proxy proxy's logs with the inverse mapping (eg: 10.168.1.2 means the client was actually 192.168.1.2). I don't know how to do this within *firewalld*.

---

**UPDATE**: the router NAT case from itself to itself can be handled using *firewalld* [policies](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.policies.html#symboliczones), but even here there are workarounds needed.

> Active Policies
>
> Policies only become active if all of the following are true.
>
> - The ingress zones list contain **at least one** regular zone or a single
>   symbolic zone.
> - The egress zones list contain **at least one** regular zone or a single
>   symbolic zone.
> - For non symbolic zones, the **zone must be active**. That is, it must have
>   interfaces or sources assigned to it.
>
> If the policy is not active then the policy has no effect.

> Symbolic zones:
>
> `HOST`
>
> This symbolic zone is for traffic flowing to or from the host running
> firewalld. This corresponds to netfilter (iptables/nftables) chains
> INPUT and OUTPUT.
>
> - If used in the egress zones list it will apply to traffic on the INPUT
>   chain.
> - If used in the **ingress** zones list it will apply to traffic on the
>   **OUTPUT** chain.

Workarounds are needed: both ingress and egress are needed, HOST can be used only once and has to be in *ingress* to have rules added to nat/output, and port-forwarding rules require that the *egress* zone has no interface added to it, else an error such as:

```
Error: INVALID_ZONE: Policy 'nat-hairpin-host': 'forward-port' cannot be used because egress zone 'trusted' has assigned interfaces
```

will happen.

So use HOST in *ingress* and recycle an unused zone: *internal* to be used as *egress* zone with instead of the `lo` interface bound to it, the host's address on the `wan` interface, to meet all prerequisites to have the policy activated (and then only when reaching the WAN address). One could use an other unused zone or even define an additional custom zone by adding an XML file (eg: by following [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-define-a-custom-firewalld-zone)) instead of *internal*. There won't be much interaction with the extra zone chosen, especially considering that filter/input and output rules always explicitly grant access to the `lo` interface.

The documentation about using policies doesn't provide much examples from CLI and describes an XML file. Still [RHEL's documentation provides examples](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-and-configuring-firewalld_configuring-and-managing-networking#con_relationship-between-policy-objects-and-zones_assembly_filtering-forwarded-traffic-between-zones) (that are unrelated to this problem). Policies can only be used along `--permanent` (and thus requiring at the end `--reload`).

The instructions below will consider 192.0.2.2/24 is the address set on `wan` to access services. So in the end:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy nat-hairpin-host
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=nat-hairpin-host --add-ingress-zone=HOST
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=nat-hairpin-host --add-egress-zone=internal
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=nat-hairpin-host --add-forward-port=port=8443:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=nat-hairpin-host --add-forward-port=port=443:proto=tcp:toport=443:toaddr=192.168.0.2
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=nat-hairpin-host --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.0.2

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-source=192.0.2.2

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Which will in the end create along plumbing rules and equivalent filter rules, something similar to this:

```
[...]

        chain nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre {
                ip daddr 192.0.2.2 jump nat_OUT_policy_nat-hairpin-host
        }

[...]

        chain nat_OUT_policy_nat-hairpin-host_allow {
                meta nfproto ipv4 tcp dport 443 dnat ip to 192.168.0.2:443
                meta nfproto ipv4 tcp dport 80 dnat ip to 192.168.0.2:80
                meta nfproto ipv4 tcp dport 8443 dnat ip to 192.168.0.2:8443
        }
```

The reverse proxy will see the source being the WAN address (the primary address for the WAN IP LAN if multiple addresses are set) since this source wasn't (and didn't have to be) changed, and that's the source the NAT router selected when reaching itself before DNAT rerouted it elsewhere.

```
# ip route get 192.0.2.2
local 192.0.2.2 dev lo src 192.0.2.2 uid 0 
    cache <local>
```

Comment: Thank you for your highly detailed answer! This really seems to be a step in the right direction, however it still doesn't work. Setting `firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.0.0/16" masquerade'` and enabling port forwarding on the internal, trusted, zone does in fact redirect requests from internal clients to the internal web server (yay), but it does so for *all* requests to port 80 or 443, no matter the hostname or IP. In practice, this thus breaks internet access for all devices in the LAN...

Comment: I will keep trying different combinations based on what you have detailed here, and I'll come back if I figure it out. Thanks!